# How to merge these codes, awk then cut

Tags: awk, cut

I am using awk in Debian.

input

```
11.22.33.44#55878:
11.22.33.43#55879:
...
...
(smtp:55.66.77.88)
(smtp:55.66.77.89)
...
...
cpe-33-22-11-99.buffalo.res.rr.com[99.11.22.33]
cpe-34-22-11-99.buffalo.res.rr.com[99.11.22.34]
...
```

Parts of sh codes (running in Debian)

```
awk '/#/ {print > "file1";next} \
/smtp/ {print > "file2";next} \
{print > "file7"}' input
#
if [ -s file1 ] ; then
    #IP type => 11.22.33.44#55878:
    cut -d'#' -f1 file1 >> output
    rm -f file1
fi
#
if [ -s file2 ] ; then
    #IP type => (smtp:55.66.77.88)
    cut -d':' -f2 file2 | cut -d')' -f1 >> output
    rm -f file2
fi
#
if [ -s file7 ] ; then
    #IP type => cpe-33-22-11-99.buffalo.res.rr.com[99.11.22.33]
    cut -d'[' -f2 file7 | cut -d']' -f1 >> output
    rm -f file7
fi
```

then output

```
11.22.33.44
11.22.33.43
55.66.77.88
55.66.77.89
99.11.22.33
99.11.22.34
```

Is it possible to merge these codes only with awk , something like

```
awk '/#/ {print | cut -d'#' -f1 > "file1";next} \
/smtp/ {print | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1 > "file2";next} \
{print | cut -d'[' -f2 file7 | cut -d']' > "file7"}' input
```

I am newbie and have no idea for this,
After search questions, still no help.
any hint?
Thanks.

Best Regard.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[][()#]|smtp:' '/#/{print $1;next} /smtp/{print $3;next} /\[/{print $2}' input
11.22.33.44
11.22.33.43
55.66.77.88
55.66.77.89
99.11.22.33
99.11.22.34
```

To save this in the file `output`:

```
awk -F'[][()#]|smtp:' '/#/{print $1;next} /smtp/{print $3;next} /\[/{print $2}' input >output
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[][()#]|smtp:'`

  This sets the field separator to (a) any of the characters `][()#` or (b) the string `smtp:`.
- `/#/{print $1;next}`

  If the line contains `#`, then print the first field and skip to the `next` line.
- `/smtp/{print $3;next}`

  If the line contains `smtp`, then print the third field and skip to the `next` line.
- `/\[/{print $2}`

  If the line contains `[`, then print the second field.

#### Variation

There is more than one way to solve this problem,  For example, using a slightly different field separator, we can still get the desired output:

```
$ awk -F'[][()#:]' '/#/{print $1;next} /smtp/{print $3;next} /\[/{print $2}' input
11.22.33.44
11.22.33.43
55.66.77.88
55.66.77.89
99.11.22.33
99.11.22.34
```

Comment: Hi John,
It's an very good answer.But I want to know ,what is the difference between :
A:     -F'[][()#]|smtp:'      
B:     -F'[[]()#]|smtp:'  

Why A is working ,B isn't ?

Comment: @NamPham Thank you. There are special rules for putting square brackets inside square brackets.  Normally, for example, `]` would terminate the grouping.  The exception is if it is the first character in the group.  Thus `[]abc]` any one of `]`,  `a`, `b`, or `c`.  By contrast, `[[]abc]` The regex `[[]a]` matches the character sequence  `[` followed by `a` followed by `]`.

Comment: @John Thanks for your so detail answer.